# How to deploy laravel project by openshift

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, openshift, s2i

I am new to openshift and want to deploy my php Laravel application using openshift commands. I know openshift uses S2I for build images from source code. I create a new application by the ssh URI of my project that is hosted on gitlab using openshift/php builder. But when expose to create route for accessing application externally, it loads test page of Apache HTTP server instead of my project home page. However this is ok for php code without any framework.

```
oc new-app openshift/php~ssh-git-uri
```

Thanks for pointing me to which builder to use. I also saw this [link](https://github.com/codecasts/s2i-laravel) but did not understand how to use it for my project.

Comment: Have you tried using S2I with the repository you linked? (`oc new-app https://github.com/codecasts/s2i-laravel~ssh-git-uri-to-your-repo`)

Comment: @Simon yes, but it raises error: unable to locate any images in image streams, local docker images with name "https://github.com/codecasts/s2i-laravel".

Comment: I guess you'll need to build and import the image first then and then use the `oc new-app` command above.